# PHP: Replace all words that are _not_ in an array

Tags: php, regex, date

I am trying to parse user-entered string dates with PHP. I need to remove all characters other than these two acceptable categories:

```
1) [0-9,\./-] (numerals, comma, period, slash, and dash)
2) An array of acceptable words:
    $monthNames=array(
        "january"=>1,
        "jan"=>1,
        "february"=>2,
        "feb"=>2
    );
```

I tried explode()ing on character word bounaries and then removing each section that is not in the array, but that led to quite a mess. Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show your code so that it's more clear what you aim for.

Comment: Are you using php's built in in_array() function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: `strtotime()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: strtotime() requires a specific format, these users enter everything from "Jan 12 1977" to "12-1-1977" to "1/12/1977" to "Turkiye". I have identified about six or seven variations that can be legal dates.

Comment: @ford: The str_replace() function will accept the array as an argument, but only for items to replace! I can foreach with in_array on the pieces, but then I get in trouble with the regex for numerals to leave in as well. That is why I didn't paste code: there doesn't seem to be much to salvage from the direction in which I was going so I was hoping to hear of a more elegant solution.

Comment: Do you really want to strip out all the whitespace?

Comment: @Petah: I see that yours is the correct answer. Please post it as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strtotime()`

```
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
```

To check for failure:

```
$str = 'Not Good';

// previous to PHP 5.1.0 you would compare with -1, instead of false
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
    echo "The string ($str) is bogus";
} else {
    echo "$str == " . date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Also `DateTime::createFromFormat()` might be useful.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

Best way to avoid that would be to make the date entry a form with only valid option and discard the rest.

Comment: This is data that has been entered over the course of years. It is not new data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regulare expression to match dates, here's a very simplistic, rudimentary one:

```
preg_match('/((Jan|Feb|Dec|\d{1,2})[ .\/-]){2,2}\d{1,4}/i', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

You'll have to add the other months, though.

Further ideas for sleepless nights:

- disallow months < 1 and > 12
- disallow Jan Jan 2011
- disallow strange years
- ...
- scrap it and find a good one ;)

I'd take a two step approach:

1. Extract something that looks date
2. Use the built-in time functions to check if one can build a timestamp that makes sense from it. If one can't, throw it out.

Answer (score 0):

*If* it is safe to assume that your $monthNames array has less than 26 elements, then the following works (though this is definitely a "hack" - I'll offer another answer if I can think of something which deserves to be called "elegant"):

```
<?php

$text = 'january 3 february 7 xyz';
print 'original string=[' . $text . "]\n";

$monthNames = array(
    'january' => 1,
    'jan' => 1,
    'february' => 2,
    'feb' => 2
    // ... presumably there are some more array elements here...
);

// Map each monthNames key to a capital letter:
$i = 65; // ASCII code for 'A'
$mmap = array();
foreach (array_keys($monthNames) as $m) {
    $c = chr($i);
    $mmap[$c] = $m;
    $i += 1;
}

// Strip out capital letters first:
$text1 = preg_replace('/[A-Z]+/', "", $text);

// Replace each month name with its letter:
$text2 = str_replace(array_keys($monthNames), array_keys($mmap), $text1);

// Filter out everything that is not allowed:
$text3 = preg_replace('/[^0-9,\.\-A-Z]/', "", $text2);

// Restore the original month names:
$text4 = str_replace(array_keys($mmap), array_keys($monthNames), $text3);

print 'filtered string=[' . $text4 . "]\n"; 
?>
```

**NOTES:**

1. If you've got more than 26 strings to exclude from filtering, then you *can* write code to exploit the same idea, but IMO it gets considerably harder to make said code understandable by humans (or by me, at any rate).
2. You can of course adjust the preg_replace() pattern to leave whitespaces alone if you decide that you really do want them after all.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this works flawlessly: What happens, if the input string is `'january 3 february 7 XYZ' ?

Comment: Indeed, your example demonstrates a missing piece of logic: all capital letters should be stripped out before the substitution step.

Comment: Modified code - added initial step to strip out capital letters.

Comment: okay then: What happens if the input string is `January 3 february 7` ?

Comment: @Cassy - The problem as originally stated excludes "January", so you would be (properly) left with "3 february 7". Now, you could argue that the $monthNames array is incomplete - which it is. In which case the proper result would depend on whether or not "January" were included as a key.